# jq: convert comma seperated values into JSON

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have a comma separated string of IP addresses (one or more)

```
nodes=192.168.56.111,192.168.56.112,192.168.56.113
```

Using `jq`, I would like to create a JSON document that looks like this:

```
{
  "clusters": [
    {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "node": {
            "hostnames": {
              "manage": [
                "192.168.56.111"
              ],
              "storage": [
                "192.168.56.111"
              ]
            },
            "zone": 1
          },
          "devices": [
            {
              "name": "/dev/sdb",
              "destroydata": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "hostnames": {
              "manage": [
                "192.168.56.112"
              ],
              "storage": [
                "192.168.56.112"
              ]
            },
            "zone": 1
          },
          "devices": [
            {
              "name": "/dev/sdb",
              "destroydata": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "hostnames": {
              "manage": [
                "192.168.56.113"
              ],
              "storage": [
                "192.168.56.113"
              ]
            },
            "zone": 1
          },
          "devices": [
            {
              "name": "/dev/sdb",
              "destroydata": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I have so far:

```
nodes=192.168.56.111,192.168.56.112,192.168.56.113

jq --arg ip "$nodes" '.clusters[].nodes[].node.hostnames.manage |= ($ip | split(","))' <<<'{"clusters":[{"nodes":[{"node":{"hostnames":{"manage":[],"storage":[]},"zone":1},"devices":[{"name":"/dev/sdb","destroydata":false}]}]}]}'
```

this has 2 problems:

1. `.clusters[].nodes[].node` is not replicated.
2. `.clusters[].nodes[].node.hostnames.storage` is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the splitting result with `map` to create the array under `.clusters[0].nodes`:

```sh
nodes=192.168.56.111,192.168.56.112,192.168.56.113

jq -R '
  {clusters: [{nodes: (./"," | map({
    node: {hostnames: {manage: [.], storage: [.]}, zone: 1},
    devices: [{name: "/dev/sdb", destroydata: false}]
  }))}]}
' <<< "$nodes"
```

```json
{
  "clusters": [
    {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "node": {
            "hostnames": {
              "manage": [
                "192.168.56.111"
              ],
              "storage": [
                "192.168.56.111"
              ]
            },
            "zone": 1
          },
          "devices": [
            {
              "name": "/dev/sdb",
              "destroydata": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "hostnames": {
              "manage": [
                "192.168.56.112"
              ],
              "storage": [
                "192.168.56.112"
              ]
            },
            "zone": 1
          },
          "devices": [
            {
              "name": "/dev/sdb",
              "destroydata": false
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "hostnames": {
              "manage": [
                "192.168.56.113"
              ],
              "storage": [
                "192.168.56.113"
              ]
            },
            "zone": 1
          },
          "devices": [
            {
              "name": "/dev/sdb",
              "destroydata": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/z3XQgY-K5g)

Comment: `<<< "$nodes"` in combination with the `-R` option makes `jq` read the string of IPs as input, so it becomes the primary context `.`. `./","` is a shorter form for `split` and generates an array of IPs. `map` then modifies each member of that array by applying its filter to them individually, so within that filter the context `.` is a single IP. And the filter itself just reproduces your structure using `.` where needed.